# kubeadm upgrade to 1.91 kube-dns failure

Tags: kubernetes

I attempted to upgrade to 1.7 to 1.9 using kubeadm, kube-dns was crashloopig.   I removed the deployment and applied the a new deployment using the latest yaml for kube-dns (replacing the clusterip with 10.96.0.10,  domain with cluster.local).

The kubedns container fails after not being able to get a valid response from the api server.   The 10.96.0.1 ip does respond to a wget on the 443 port from all servers in the cluster (403 forbidden response).

```
E0104 21:51:42.732805       1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/dns/pkg/dns/dns.go:147: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E0104 21:51:42.732971       1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/dns/pkg/dns/dns.go:150: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

Is this a connection issue, configuration issue, or a security model change that is causing the errors in the log?

Thanks.

```
    $ kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
ubuntu80   Ready     master    165d      v1.9.1
ubuntu81   Ready     <none>    165d      v1.9.1
ubuntu82   Ready     <none>    165d      v1.9.1
ubuntu83   Ready     <none>    163d      v1.9.1

$ kubectl get all --namespace=kube-system
NAME                            DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                   AGE
ds/kube-flannel-ds              4         4         4         0            4           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64   165d
ds/kube-proxy                   4         4         4         4            4           <none>                          165d
ds/traefik-ingress-controller   3         3         3         3            3           <none>                          165d

NAME                   DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deploy/kube-dns        1         1         1            0           1h
deploy/tiller-deploy   1         1         1            1           163d

NAME                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
rs/kube-dns-6c857864fb        1         1         0         1h
rs/tiller-deploy-3341511835   1         1         1         105d

NAME                            DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                   AGE
ds/kube-flannel-ds              4         4         4         0            4           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64   165d
ds/kube-proxy                   4         4         4         4            4           <none>                          165d
ds/traefik-ingress-controller   3         3         3         3            3           <none>                          165d

NAME                   DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deploy/kube-dns        1         1         1            0           1h
deploy/tiller-deploy   1         1         1            1           163d

NAME                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
rs/kube-dns-6c857864fb        1         1         0         1h
rs/tiller-deploy-3341511835   1         1         1         105d

NAME                                  READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
po/etcd-ubuntu80                      1/1       Running            1          16d
po/kube-apiserver-ubuntu80            1/1       Running            1          2h
po/kube-controller-manager-ubuntu80   1/1       Running            1          2h
po/kube-dns-6c857864fb-grhxp          1/3       CrashLoopBackOff   52         1h
po/kube-flannel-ds-07npj              2/2       Running            32         165d
po/kube-flannel-ds-169lh              2/2       Running            26         165d
po/kube-flannel-ds-50c56              2/2       Running            27         163d
po/kube-flannel-ds-wkd7j              2/2       Running            29         165d
po/kube-proxy-495n7                   1/1       Running            1          2h
po/kube-proxy-9g7d2                   1/1       Running            1          2h
po/kube-proxy-d856z                   1/1       Running            0          2h
po/kube-proxy-kzmcc                   1/1       Running            0          2h
po/kube-scheduler-ubuntu80            1/1       Running            1          2h
po/tiller-deploy-3341511835-m3x26     1/1       Running            2          58d
po/traefik-ingress-controller-51r7d   1/1       Running            4          105d
po/traefik-ingress-controller-sf6lc   1/1       Running            4          105d
po/traefik-ingress-controller-xz1rt   1/1       Running            5          105d

NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
svc/kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   1h
svc/kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.101.112.198   <none>        443/TCP         165d
svc/tiller-deploy          ClusterIP   10.98.117.242    <none>        44134/TCP       163d
svc/traefik-web-ui         ClusterIP   10.110.215.194   <none>        80/TCP          165d


$ kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c kubedns
I0104 21:51:12.730927       1 dns.go:48] version: 1.14.6-3-gc36cb11
I0104 21:51:12.731643       1 server.go:69] Using configuration read from directory: /kube-dns-config with period 10s
I0104 21:51:12.731673       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --alsologtostderr="false"
I0104 21:51:12.731679       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --config-dir="/kube-dns-config"
I0104 21:51:12.731683       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --config-map=""
I0104 21:51:12.731686       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --config-map-namespace="kube-system"
I0104 21:51:12.731688       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --config-period="10s"
I0104 21:51:12.731693       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --dns-bind-address="0.0.0.0"
I0104 21:51:12.731695       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --dns-port="10053"
I0104 21:51:12.731713       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --domain="cluster.local."
I0104 21:51:12.731717       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --federations=""
I0104 21:51:12.731723       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --healthz-port="8081"
I0104 21:51:12.731726       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --initial-sync-timeout="1m0s"
I0104 21:51:12.731729       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --kube-master-url=""
I0104 21:51:12.731733       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --kubecfg-file=""
I0104 21:51:12.731735       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --log-backtrace-at=":0"
I0104 21:51:12.731740       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --log-dir=""
I0104 21:51:12.731743       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --log-flush-frequency="5s"
I0104 21:51:12.731746       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --logtostderr="true"
I0104 21:51:12.731748       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --nameservers=""
I0104 21:51:12.731751       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --stderrthreshold="2"
I0104 21:51:12.731753       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --v="2"
I0104 21:51:12.731756       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --version="false"
I0104 21:51:12.731761       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --vmodule=""
I0104 21:51:12.731798       1 server.go:194] Starting SkyDNS server (0.0.0.0:10053)
I0104 21:51:12.731979       1 server.go:213] Skydns metrics enabled (/metrics:10055)
I0104 21:51:12.731987       1 dns.go:146] Starting endpointsController
I0104 21:51:12.731991       1 dns.go:149] Starting serviceController
I0104 21:51:12.732457       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for tcp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I0104 21:51:12.732467       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for udp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I0104 21:51:13.232355       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
I0104 21:51:13.732395       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
I0104 21:51:14.232389       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
I0104 21:51:14.732389       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
I0104 21:51:15.232369       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...

I0104 21:51:42.732629       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
E0104 21:51:42.732805       1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/dns/pkg/dns/dns.go:147: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E0104 21:51:42.732971       1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/dns/pkg/dns/dns.go:150: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
I0104 21:51:43.232257       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...

I0104 21:51:51.232379       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
I0104 21:51:51.732371       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
I0104 21:51:52.232390       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
I0104 21:52:11.732376       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
I0104 21:52:12.232382       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
F0104 21:52:12.732377       1 dns.go:167] Timeout waiting for initialization



$ kubectl describe po/kube-dns-6c857864fb-grhxp --namespace=kube-system
Name:           kube-dns-6c857864fb-grhxp
Namespace:      kube-system
Node:           ubuntu82/10.80.82.1
Start Time:     Fri, 05 Jan 2018 01:55:48 +0530
Labels:         k8s-app=kube-dns
                pod-template-hash=2741342096
Annotations:    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod=
Status:         Running
IP:             10.244.2.12
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/kube-dns-6c857864fb
Containers:
  kubedns:
    Container ID:  docker://3daa4233f54fa251abdcdfe73d2e71179356f5da45983d19fe66a3f18bab8d13
    Image:         gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64:1.14.7
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64@sha256:f5bddc71efe905f4e4b96f3ca346414be6d733610c1525b98fff808f93966680
    Ports:         10053/UDP, 10053/TCP, 10055/TCP
    Args:
      --domain=cluster.local.
      --dns-port=10053
      --config-dir=/kube-dns-config
      --v=2
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Fri, 05 Jan 2018 03:21:12 +0530
      Finished:     Fri, 05 Jan 2018 03:22:12 +0530
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  26
    Limits:
      memory:  170Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   70Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:10054/healthcheck/kubedns delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Readiness:  http-get http://:8081/readiness delay=3s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      PROMETHEUS_PORT:  10055
    Mounts:
      /kube-dns-config from kube-dns-config (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-dns-token-cpzzw (ro)
  dnsmasq:
    Container ID:  docker://a40a34e6fdf7176ea148fdb1f21d157c5d264e44bd14183ed9d19164a742fb65
    Image:         gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64:1.14.7
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64@sha256:6cfb9f9c2756979013dbd3074e852c2d8ac99652570c5d17d152e0c0eb3321d6
    Ports:         53/UDP, 53/TCP
    Args:
      -v=2
      -logtostderr
      -configDir=/etc/k8s/dns/dnsmasq-nanny
      -restartDnsmasq=true
      --
      -k
      --cache-size=1000
      --no-negcache
      --log-facility=-
      --server=/cluster.local/127.0.0.1#10053
      --server=/in-addr.arpa/127.0.0.1#10053
      --server=/ip6.arpa/127.0.0.1#10053
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 05 Jan 2018 03:24:44 +0530
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Fri, 05 Jan 2018 03:17:33 +0530
      Finished:     Fri, 05 Jan 2018 03:19:33 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  27
    Requests:
      cpu:        150m
      memory:     20Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:10054/healthcheck/dnsmasq delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/k8s/dns/dnsmasq-nanny from kube-dns-config (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-dns-token-cpzzw (ro)
  sidecar:
    Container ID:  docker://c05b33a08344f15b0d1a1e8fee39cc05b6d9de6a24db6d2cd05e92c2706fc03c
    Image:         gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64:1.14.7
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64@sha256:f80f5f9328107dc516d67f7b70054354b9367d31d4946a3bffd3383d83d7efe8
    Port:          10054/TCP
    Args:
      --v=2
      --logtostderr
      --probe=kubedns,127.0.0.1:10053,kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local,5,SRV
      --probe=dnsmasq,127.0.0.1:53,kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local,5,SRV
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 05 Jan 2018 02:09:25 +0530
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    2
      Started:      Fri, 05 Jan 2018 01:55:50 +0530
      Finished:     Fri, 05 Jan 2018 02:08:20 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  1
    Requests:
      cpu:        10m
      memory:     20Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:10054/metrics delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-dns-token-cpzzw (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          False
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  kube-dns-config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      kube-dns
    Optional:  true
  kube-dns-token-cpzzw:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  kube-dns-token-cpzzw
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     CriticalAddonsOnly
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------                 ----                ----               -------
  Warning  Unhealthy              46m (x57 over 1h)   kubelet, ubuntu82  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.2.12:8081/readiness: dial tcp 10.244.2.12:8081: getsockopt: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy              36m (x42 over 1h)   kubelet, ubuntu82  Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
  Warning  BackOff                31m (x162 over 1h)  kubelet, ubuntu82  Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Killing                26m (x13 over 1h)   kubelet, ubuntu82  Killing container with id docker://dnsmasq:Container failed liveness probe.. Container will be killed and recreated.
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  21m                 kubelet, ubuntu82  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "kube-dns-token-cpzzw"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  21m                 kubelet, ubuntu82  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "kube-dns-config"
  Normal   Pulled                 21m                 kubelet, ubuntu82  Container image "gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64:1.14.7" already present on machine
  Normal   Started                21m                 kubelet, ubuntu82  Started container
  Normal   Created                21m                 kubelet, ubuntu82  Created container
  Normal   Started                19m (x2 over 21m)   kubelet, ubuntu82  Started container
  Normal   Created                19m (x2 over 21m)   kubelet, ubuntu82  Created container
  Normal   Pulled                 19m (x2 over 21m)   kubelet, ubuntu82  Container image "gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64:1.14.7" already present on machine
  Warning  Unhealthy              19m (x4 over 20m)   kubelet, ubuntu82  Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
  Warning  Unhealthy              16m (x22 over 21m)  kubelet, ubuntu82  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.2.12:8081/readiness: dial tcp 10.244.2.12:8081: getsockopt: connection refused
  Normal   Killing                6m (x6 over 19m)    kubelet, ubuntu82  Killing container with id docker://dnsmasq:Container failed liveness probe.. Container will be killed and recreated.
  Warning  BackOff                1m (x65 over 20m)   kubelet, ubuntu82  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Comment: I gave up... used kubectl --export to backup the running deployments and other config to yaml files,  then started over creating a new cluster after doing a kubeadm reset.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have no idea how to make kube-dns recognize that my apiserver listens on 6443 and not 443.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubedns 1.14.7 does not work well with kubernetes 1.9.1. In my case, kubedns was trying to connect to apiserver using 443 and not, as configured, 6443.

When I changed the image version to 1.14.8 (newest - [kubedns github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns)), kubedns recognized the apiserver port properly. No problems any more:

```
kubectl edit deploy kube-dns  --namespace=kube-system
#change to the image version to  1.14.8  and works
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I saw issues with `kube-dns` `1.14.7` too. Use the latest `kube-dns` version `1.14.8` in https://github.com/kubernetes/dns/releases by doing:

```
kubectl edit deploy kube-dns --namespace=kube-system
# change the image version in the "Image:" field to 1.14.8
```

If the issue is still seen, also do:

```
kubectl create configmap --namespace=kube-system kube-dns
kubectl delete pod <name of kube-dns pod> --namespace=kube-system
# kube-dns should restart and work now
```